# Questions regarding the dimension initialization of multiple numpy arrays within a single numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, quantum-computing

Given that we have 3 [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), each with dimension (2x2). As shown below:

```
X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=complex)
Y = np.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]], dtype=complex)
Z = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]], dtype=complex)
```

Now if I put these each individual (2x2) matrices as entries to another (2x2) matrices. Say:

```
A = np.array([[X, 0], [0, Y]])
B = np.array([[X, X], [Y, Y]])
```

Weirdly, A has a dim of (2x2) - which is ideally what I want - and B has a dim of (2, 2, 2, 2)whatever this is, as show below

```
A = np.array([[X, 0], [0, Y]])

A.shape
Out[131]: (2, 2)

B = np.array([[X, X], [Y, Y]])

B.shape
Out[133]: (2, 2, 2, 2)
```

On the other hand, say let `C` be a `(1x3)` matrix and `D` be a `(1x2)` matrix, e.g.

```
C = np.array([[X, Y, 0]])
D = np.array([[X, Y]])
```

again if we look at the dimensions of the initialized matrices

```
C = np.array([[X, Y, 0]])

C.shape
Out[136]: (1, 3)

D = np.array([[X, Y]])

D.shape
Out[138]: (1, 2, 2, 2)
```

So it seems that whenever I initialize arrays in an array like these, if there's mixed data type as entries i.e. matrices and integers like in `A`and`C`, it gives me the sensible shape that I want i.e. dimension`(2,2)`, with "hidden" dimensions of `(2x2)` for each entries. But as soon as the entries are just strictly matrices like in `B`and`D`, it gives me insensible dimension such as `(2, 2, 2, 2)`. So my question is:

**How do I initialize an `(n, n)` numpy array(matrix) with strictly `(2, 2)` matrices as entries, and still preserve its `(n, n)` dimensionality i.e. instead of giving me some weird numpy dimension `(w, x, y, z)`?**

The reason why I want this is because I'm doing computations with operators in quantum mechanics, with these Pauli matrices, such as the `X`, `Y` and `Z`, as quantum gates in quantum computation. So if I have some state `rho` which is also a `(2x2)` matrix. Let

```
rho = np.array([[1, 0],
                [0, 0]])
```

And let `RHO` be the `(2x2)` diagonal matrix who's entries are the `(2x2) rho` matrices.

```
RHO = np.array([[rho, 0],
                [0, rho]])
```

I wish to compute something like `np.dot(D, RHO)` such that it gives

```
np.array([np.dot(X, rho), 0],
         [0, np.dot(Y, rho)])
```

And I've checked on python that the dot products of two (2x2) matrices with (2x2) matrices as entries, its entries multiplications will all be dot product too.

My motivation for all of the stuff I've talked about above is that I'm hoping to use these properties as means to vectorize my algorithm. Currently a very crude example of my algorithm looks something like this:

```
for i in (integer_1):
    for j in (integer_2):
        #do something that involves operations with sums of dot products of many matrices#
```

and vectorize it so that it could potentially become

```
for i in (integer_1):
        #do something that involves operations with multiples of matrices with dot product of matrices as its entries#
```

Which might potentially work, or not! But I'm curious to see if this method of mine will produce a speed up.
I hope I've explained my problems well.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit(1)**

[I've added latex formatted maths so hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x1lc.png)

```py
def compute_channel_operation(rho, operators):
    """
    Given a quantum state's density function rho, the effect of the
    channel on this state is:
    rho -> sum_{i=1}^n E_i * rho * E_i^dagger
    Args:
        rho (2x2 matrix): Density function
        operators (list): List of operators(matrices)
    Returns:
        number: The result of applying the list of operators
    """
    operation = [E@rho@E.conj().T for i, E in enumerate(operators)]
    return np.sum(operation, axis=0)
```

[So then I was hoping that instead of using loops, this direct multiplication of tensor method might be quicker as I scale up my simulation, say having to do this 1 million times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK6Vj.png)
The thing is K here should be a list of any (1xn) dimensions i.e. [I] or [I, X] or [I, X, Y] or [I, X, Y, Z]. I understand that here X = X^{\dagger} and so will Y and Z, but I'll have situations in my simulation where that wont be the case.

I hope I've now explained it clearly.

Comment: Do you want A and B to be 4x4 matrices, or 2x2x2x2 tensors?

Comment: I want my B(with (2, 2, 2, 2)) to have the same dim as A(with (2, 2)). Or do they basically have the same dimension?

Comment: But what do you mean "put matrices as the entries of another matrix"? Do you want to create a block matrix, or really a matrix of matrices (whatever that is)? In NumPy, a `(2, 2)` matrix of objects is not really useful, as most math operations will stop working... Maybe you can give some example input data, some of the operations you want to perform, and desired output data?

Comment: Please see my edit above. Thanks :)

Comment: I have amended a speedup solution for your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(2, 2, 2, 2)` is not a *weird dimension*, it is just a 4D tensor of shape 2x2x2x2

The reason why you are seing different shapes for `A` and `B` is because you are setting `A` with a scalar `0` instead of a 2x2 zero matrix. Change it to

```
A = np.array([[X, np.zeros((2, 2))], [np.zeros((2, 2)), Y]])
B = np.array([[X, X], [Y, Y]])
```

And you will get 2x2x2x2 tensors for both.

Or change it to

```
C = np.vstack([
    np.hstack([X, np.zeros((2, 2))]),
    np.hstack([np.zeros((2, 2)), Y])
])
D = np.vstack([
    np.hstack([X, X]),
    np.hstack([Y, Y])
])
```

And you will get 4x4 matrices.

You can also transform from one form to the other using

```
E = A.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(4, 4)
F = B.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(4, 4)

np.allclose(C, E)  # True
np.allclose(D, F)  # True
```

and back

```
G = E.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
H = F.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)

np.allclose(A, G)  # True
np.allclose(B, H)  # True
```

**EDIT:** Regarding your function `compute_channel_operation()`, you can speed it up considerably if you don't perform a list comprehension but vectorize the operation and pass in a 3D tensor with all your operations

```
rho = np.random.rand(2, 2)
operators = [np.random.rand(2, 2) for _ in range(1000)]
operators_tensor = np.asarray(operators)  # same as np.random.rand(1000, 2, 2)

def compute_channel_operation(rho, operators):
    operation = [E@rho@E.conj().T for i, E in enumerate(operators)]
    return np.sum(operation, axis=0)

def compute_channel_operation2(rho, operators):
    return np.sum(operators @ rho @ operators.transpose(0, 2, 1).conj(), axis=0)

A = compute_channel_operation(rho, operators)
B = compute_channel_operation(rho, operators_tensor)
C = compute_channel_operation2(rho, operators_tensor)

np.allclose(A, B) # True
np.allclose(A, C) # True

%timeit compute_channel_operation(rho, operators)
# 6.95 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit compute_channel_operation(rho, operators_tensor)
# 7.53 ms ± 141 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit compute_channel_operation2(rho, operators_tensor)
# 416 µs ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: For a density operator(2x2 matrix) `rho = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]])`, is there a quick way of generating an (nxn) diagonal tensor with `rho` as the diagonal entries?i.e. for (2x2) or (2,2,2,2) `tensor = np.array([[rho, 0], [0, rho]])` or for (3x3) or (3,3,2,2) `tensor = np.array([[rho, 0, 0], [0, rho, 0], [0, 0, rho]])` ?

Comment: Yes, `scipy.linalg.block_diag()`. But keep in mind that your computation will become very inefficient for large matrices.

Comment: Your code is exactly what I want, so I'll officially accept it, so thank you!!But I realised the speed-up is only significant in the case where the size of `operators` is big i.e. (1,100), which in my case mine will only be an array with max dim of (1,4). So it's now apparent to me that for the speedup I want, I should be vectorising the 2 aforementioned `i` and `j` loops that I'm running on top of my `compute_channel_operation`, but I'm not sure how I can do that, and I'm not entirely fine with posting my whole code on here. Perhaps if you're still interested, you can have a look in private?

Comment: `compute_channel_operation2()` is a vectorized solution to your function. But if that doesn't solve your problem, just create another question and optionally link it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971113/how-to-implement-vectorization-over-loops-of-block-multiplication-via-tensor-mul here it is

Answer (score 0):

```
In [343]: X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=complex) 
     ...: Y = np.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]], dtype=complex) 
     ...: Z = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]], dtype=complex)                                                        
In [344]: X                                                                                                     
Out[344]: 
array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
       [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])
In [345]: Y                                                                                                     
Out[345]: 
array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
       [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]])
In [346]: Z                                                                                                     
Out[346]: 
array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]])
```

`np.array` tries to make a multidimensional numeric array, and failing that makes an object dtype array (or raises an error).

```
In [347]: np.array([X,0])                                                                                       
Out[347]: 
array([array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
       [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]]), 0], dtype=object)
```

This array is basically the same as the list `[X,0]` - it contains pointers or references to the objects `X` and the number `0`.

But given 2 (or more) arrays that match in size, it makes a higher dimensional numeric array.  For example a (2,2,2) array with complex dtype.

```
In [348]: np.array([X,Y])                                                                                       
Out[348]: 
array([[[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
        [ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j]],

       [[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
        [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]]])
```

`block`,or some combination of `concatenate/stack` can make a 2d array.  For example a (2,4) complex array:

```
In [349]: np.block([X,Y])                                                                                       
Out[349]: 
array([[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
       [ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]])
```

To make an object dtype array containing `X` and Y`, I can do:

```
In [356]: xy = np.empty((2,), object)                                                                           
In [357]: xy[0]= X                                                                                              
In [358]: xy[1]= Y                                                                                              
In [359]: xy                                                                                                    
Out[359]: 
array([array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
       [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]]),
       array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
       [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]])], dtype=object)
```

This `empty` followed by individual assignment is the most robust way of building an object dtype array.  It gets around multidimensional result shown in `Out[348]`.

I don't know whether any of these approaches helps with your calculation goals.  I haven't studied your description enough.  But keep in mind that the fast `numpy` code works with multidimensional numeric (including `complex`) arrays (such as `Out[348]`).  Math using object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss, and nearly always slower.

`@` matrix multiplication works with `X`, `Y`, `Out[348]`, `rho` etc.  but not with `Out[347]` or `RHO`. `+` works with the object dtype arrays, provided the elements themselves support addition.